# select a photo from library and open it in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have 2 views. First view contain two buttons: Camera and Library. When i select Library i access the camera roll. I wanna select a photo and open it in another view. Until now i write this functions:

```
- (IBAction)chooseExistingPhoto :(id)sender{

NSLog(@"chooseExistingPhoto");
pickerLibrary = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerLibrary.delegate = self;
[pickerLibrary setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:pickerLibrary animated:YES completion:NULL];
NSLog(@"chooseExistingPhoto END");
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

NSLog(@"imagePickerController");
imagePreview.hidden = YES;
captureImage.hidden = NO;
image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
//[captureImage setImage:image];

//ImageLibViewController *svc = [[ImageLibViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageLibViewController" bundle:nil];
//svc.imageLibModified.image  = image;

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^(void){

    UIStoryboard     * storyboardd    = self.storyboard;
    NSString         * storyboardName = [storyboardd valueForKey:@"name"];
    UIStoryboard     * storyboard     = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    ImageLibViewController * vc       = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"imageLib"];

    vc.imageLibModified.image = image;

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    //[picker showViewController:vc sender:vc];
}];
```

witch open my image in the same view. How could I open this image in another view?
and my second question is where i put my session in viewdidload or viewdidappear ?

Comment: i talk about session because i open my camera in my first view.

Comment: try to do so without dismissing the present view controller, i mean remove the dismissViewController but keep the code written in the completion block 
let me know what happens

Comment: I tried but it does not work because if i don't use dismissViewController I will never quit Library.

Comment: someone can help me !

Comment: @AlgroDev did you try my answer

Comment: yes but it doesn't work,thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code to the view controller where you want to display camera roll

//This will listen the notification from the other view controller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(openGallery) name:@"openGallery:" object:nil];




-(void)openGallery
{

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    NSLog(@"open gallery");
}
```

//This as button click action, when you click the button it will notify the other view, another view has listeners and it will perform the specified method

```
   - (IBAction)chooseExistingPhoto :(id)sender
    {

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]     postNotificationName:@"openGallery:" object:nil userInfo:nil];

    }
```

Write the delegate methods and protocols confirmation and everything in the view controller where you going to display the camera roll. Just put the notifier in button action.

This will work I have done this

Comment: dont use that pop, use your view

Comment: thks vijeesh, how i can retrieve image zoomed from lib

Comment: no, but when i choose image in lib they display it and i can zoom it, the image is displaying in the first view but not zooming

Comment: Enable the view's user interaction, currently it is disabled that is why zoom is not working

Comment: in your code i used this (picker.allowsEditing = YES) what I have needed thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**swift 3**

**To open camera**

```
  if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.front;
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

**To open Library**

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

**Delegate methods**

```
 private func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    _ = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage //get the image from info
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true,completion: nil)
}
```

**Note : here in code imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
if you choose allowsEditing = true then you need to change UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage instead of UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage**